# htm file doesn't loaded with query string

Tags: javascript, html, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm trying to get a query string from htm file.
But when I'm writing a "?param=1" in the end of the .htm url - the file not loaded and I don't see anything in this page - The error I get is: "Incorrect document syntax".
When I'm opened this url without the query string in the end, its opened normally.

This is my htm file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Url sender</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-size: 12px;
            margin: 0px 10px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = getQueryString();

        function getQueryString() {
var queryString = window.location.search.replace(new RegExp("^(?:.*[&\\?]" + escape("param").replace(/[\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "(?:\\=([^&]*))?)?.*$", "i"), "$1");
            SendUrlsToServer(queryString);
        }

    </script>
        <p>
            test paragraph
        </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

(The function SendUrlsToServer its from another js file).
I need to get a query string in this url..
This htm file is web resource in crm.
Any help how can I solve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CRM, a webpage (HTML) or Silverlight web resource page can only accept a single custom parameter called data.
anything else will cause problem.

[Read More...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327945.aspx?hadas=3$ortal=ef)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for "urls" in the parameter but sending "param" instead !

Change `escape("urls")` to `escape("param")` if you will be sending "param"

Try below code snippet

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Url sender</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0px 10px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = getQueryString();

function getQueryString() {
var queryString = window.location.search.replace(new RegExp("^(?:.*[&\\?]" + escape("params").replace(/[\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "(?:\\=([^&]*))?)?.*$", "i"), "$1");
SendUrlsToServer(queryString);
}
function SendUrlsToServer(x)
{
if(x.length > 0)
   alert(x);
}
</script>
<p>
    test paragraph
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My bad...
I'm search for "param", but the file will not opened no matter what I wrote after the "?" in the end of the url.

Comment: whats the error in the error console? I think the function you are trying to call might not be there in the file.js. See sample code in my answer

Comment: It's not the problem... when I tried open this htm file without the "?param=1" in the end of the url - it opens normally and go to this function.
But when I write "?..." in the end of the url, I get the error "Incorrect document syntax"

Comment: I am not sure why you are seeing that error, I dont get that error when I run it on my PC (I am using Chrome)

Comment: I'm using IE, but I tried opened it in Chrome and it doesn't work too with this Error: "HTTP Error 500 - Internal Server Error Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1"

Comment: Looks like you are using this with ASP.NET? Can you show a snippet?