# How to pass current entity Id to my Silverlight webresource?

Tags: javascript, silverlight, dynamics-crm

I have a silverlight webresource in my CRM 2015 online, that I open using a javascript webresource. This web resource is through a ribbon button of the Opportunity entity. I need to pass the current opened opportunity to the silverlight web resource. I've managed to get the OpportunityId but still I can't pass it to the Silverlight web resource.

My javascript webresource code:

```
function OpenSilverLightControl()
 {
     var Id=Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();

    window.open('https://crm.mycrm.com//WebResources/new_/MyCRMQuoteTestPage.html',null,500,600);
 }
```

EDIT:

I tried using QueryString but it produces an Internal Server Error.

This is my link: https://crm.mycrm.com//WebResources/new_/mycrmOpportunityQuoteTestPage.html?oppid={7A594863-1C1F-E511-80C8-02E7484A2B2F}

also this : https://crm.mycrm.com//WebResources/new_/mycrmOpportunityQuoteTestPage.html?oppid=7A594863-1C1F-E511-80C8-02E7484A2B2F

both give "500 - Internal server error"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From user3491963 answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316914/htm-file-doesnt-loaded-with-query-string) question
as well as jasonscript and Unlockedluca answers in the current question, 
I was able to use the **Querystring parameter** BUT it has to be with name "**data**" any other name won't work.

Answer (score 2):

This is normally done using a query string variable

```
function OpenSilverLightControl(){
    var Id=Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
    var url = 'https://crm.mycrm.com//WebResources/new_/MyCRMQuoteTestPage.html?elementid=' + Id;

    window.open(url,null,500,600);
}
```

Then in the Silverlight application you can read the querystring value

Comment: I tried that and I got Server Error: "500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."

Comment: This is my link: https://crm.mycrm.com//WebResources/new_/mycrmOpportunityQuoteTestPage.html?oppid={7A594863-1C1F-E511-80C8-02E7484A2B2F}

also this : https://crm.mycrm.com//WebResources/new_/mycrmOpportunityQuoteTestPage.html?oppid=7A594863-1C1F-E511-80C8-02E7484A2B2F

both give "Server not found error"

Answer (score 1):

Add it as querystring and parse it in your Silverlight webresponse?

You could do it like:

```
window.open('https://crm.mycrm.com//WebResources/new_/MyCRMQuoteTestPage.html?id='+id'
```

And in your Silverlight resource:

```
function getQueryString (name) {
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars[strName];
}
```

And call the function like: `getQueryString("id");`

Comment: I tried that and I got Server Error: "500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."